# Are Qt signals to another thread queued?

Tags: c++, qt5, qthread

If I have:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:

  Worker();

public slots:

  void doStuff();
}
```

And run it like this (assume we are in class `Foo`):

```
auto worker = new Worker;
connect(this, &Foo::stuffRequested, worker, &Worker::doStuff);
QThread workerThread;
worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
workerThread.start();
```

Now if I emit `stuffRequested()` so frequently that the Worker cannot keep up what happens? Are the signal invokations queued?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html

Comment: Hmm...I take that as a yes :D